docker "copy . ." error Cannot copy to non-directory
When I run> docker build -t test .
Getting this response:

=> ERROR [ 8/10] COPY . .                                                                                                                                              0.1s

[ 8/10] COPY . .:
------ cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ssoienfsoienf/merged/home/bots/StreamBot/node_modules/@dank074/discord-video-stream
PS C:\User\alks\Documents\Development\DiscordBots\StreamBot>


Not sure how to resolve this issue let me know what other info is needed and I can update.
Here is the Dockerfile:
# Use the official nodejs lts alpine image as the base image
FROM node:lts-alpine

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /home/bots/StreamBot

# Install important deps
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual .builds-deps build-base python3 ffmpeg

# Install pnpm
RUN npm install pnpm -g

# Copy package.json
COPY package.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN pnpm install

# Install node dev types
RUN pnpm install --save-dev @types/node

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN pnpm run build

# Specify the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 3000

# Create videos folder
RUN mkdir -p ./videos

# Command to run the application
CMD ["pnpm", "run", "start"]


At a guess, add a .dockerignore file with node_modules in it

This question is similar to: COPY with docker but with exclusion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Phil this solved my issue thank you sooo much

@Phil I didn't realize this was the same issue it is, thank you

It's just a side effect I think. You really don't want to copy over the host node_modules though

the issue is with symlinks created when building node-modules. You should never copy node_modules anyway, so .dockerignore is the way to go.
